# ¿que significa NOT en UPDATE SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Busque en Google y no halle respuesta para esto me parece mas facil preguntar aqui.

```
UPDATE table
SET Paciente = Juan Perez
WHERE RowID IN NOT (1,2.3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El operador [`IN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) permite especificar múltiples valores con los que una columna puede coincidir. Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabla
WHERE nombre IN ('Fulano', 'Mengano')
```

Para lo opuesto, se usa [`NOT IN`](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/in.php), para especificar la condición de que una columna no tenga uno de los valores listados.

En el ejemplo que publicaste, se actualizan todos los registros que **no tengan** un `RowID` igual a 1, 2 o 3.

```
UPDATE table
SET Paciente = 'Juan Perez'
WHERE RowID NOT IN (1,2,3)
```

- Nótese que el `NOT` va antes del `IN`, y que el valor del campo debería ir como texto entre comillas.

Answer (score 3):

En general significa `NO`, en este caso que `NO pertenezca a un conjunto`. Y en tu contexto es que el RowID `NO` sea ninguno de esos